# Blazor Client - error NETSDK1082: 'browser-wasm'

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a simple blazor wa project hosted option selected. In the client side of the project in the project it automatically comes with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">`. I then added a few nuget packages before writing any code and when I clean the solution and even rebuild the solution it gives me the error:

> error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

I looked it up and saw that one solution to this is to change the first line in the `.csproj` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` instead of what it comes with by default. I did so but then when I run just the client it says 404. Then if I remove the extra packages and put it back to the default sdk it works. Is there a reason why I am getting this error with those packages? I created a blazor wa hosted .net 6 project btw.

my client.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ProtectedBrowserStorage" Version="5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.13.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  
</Project>
```

Comment: work through removing the packages one  by one until you find the culprit.  One of the will almost certainly not be 6.0 compatible.  For WASM the project should be Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.

Comment: Thank you, yes I did that and realized some of the packages were not compatible.

Comment: What really helps here is to use `dotnet build -v detailed` (Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) for better debug information. In my case, my libraries were on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` in version 6.0.10 and some derived libraries had references to the same, but with version 6.9.0 which caused the issues.

Comment: Short update: The inconsistencies were one issue, but not the only one. Still didn't find it though...

Comment: the detailed build takes forever and generates thousands of lines of errors.  Is there a VS tool or plugin that can diagnose this?

Comment: MarkCo, how did you determine what packages were incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just `.csproject` but also check `project.assets.json` . Usually the culprit is the non web assembly compatible packages. The easier way is to check your NuGet dependencies and verify if your third party packages are compatible with WebAssembly

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36711#issuecomment-922801873

Comment: Muchly appreciated! Found out that some of my packages are not compatible