# Blazor Web Assembly/Server App No Longer Builds or seems to exist. Packages 'Disappeared'

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, blazor

I am developing a Web assembly app with the template model which I had so far successfully migrated to .Net 6. It follws the template format of Client, Server, Shared. All working so far.

I wanted to move the ApplicationDBContext into the SHARED project as it feels a bit out of sorts in the SERVER Proj, and I need a another Webjob Project to reference it so it seemed like a good idea... (Checking in before I did it - just in case).

I moved it and changed the namespace and rebuilt the SHARED. Then thinking I would have a load of namespace fixups to do. Cutting a possibly long story short, the App then failed to build with ALL the packages in the client showing a yellow 'warning' triangle, but without indicating what the error/warning is:
[image]

I am also seeing this error:
[image]

Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    RaffleGames.Client

I decided to abandon the tidy up and revert to how it was... Sadly though, it is now broken with the same errors.

If I remove the reference to the SHARED project, then the  warnings dissappear, but of course the CLIENT will no longer build.

Adding it back causes it to build but again with the above error.

I did wonder if some of the dependencies arent allowed in a blazor app as I did see that somewhere.. heres the project re-added:

[image]

I have re-started VS, and the machine, just in case... but to no avail.
I realise this is not a very clear question, but obviously something changed as a part of the build process and and I am looking for some pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhere in your code or your libraries referenced by the WASM project you have a referenced assembly that is incompatible with WASM.   I can't see it, but I've had the problem and in my case it was caused by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` in one of my project libraries.    I separated out all the controller code into a separate library that only the server project referenced.

Comment: Check your NuGet packages and make sure they are compatible with WebAssembly. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220739/blazor-client-error-netsdk1082-browser-wasm) can help you?

Comment: Thank you both... Yes, I think that is the issue, as I intimated in the question. It now builds ok, but something is stopping the blazor element from deploying... I'll carry on searching...