# Can not Use Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When I am trying to add the Nuget package `Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore` to my ASP.NET Core web assembly project, I get the following error:

> Für "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" stand für den angegebenen RuntimeIdentifier "browser-wasm" kein Runtimepaket zur Verfügung.

I am sorry that this is in German, it could not be unlocalized.

Translated it means that for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App for the given runtime identifier `browser-wasm` is not available.

The error points to this file:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.304\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Try to check your NuGet dependencies and verify if your third party packages are compatible with WebAssembly. Maybe this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220739/blazor-client-error-netsdk1082-browser-wasm is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may meet the problem that using .NET 7 version of the .NET WebAssembly build tools in  projects built with .NET 6.

> The .NET 7 version of the .NET WebAssembly build tools are
> incompatible with existing projects built with .NET 6.    Projects
> using the .NET WebAssembly build tools that need to support both .NET
> 6 and .NET 7 must use multi-targeting. The new `wasm-tools-net6`
> workload includes the .NET WebAssembly build tools for .NET 6 projects
> so that they can be used with the .NET 7 SDK.

You can check  the Installed Workload list by:

```
dotnet workload list
```

Use the `wasm-tools-net6` workload for .NET 6 projects when developing apps with the .NET 7 SDK. To install the wasm-tools-net6 workload, execute the following command from an administrative command shell:

```
dotnet workload install wasm-tools-net6
```

You can read [.NET WebAssembly build tools for .NET 6 projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/60-70?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#net-webassembly-build-tools-for-net-6-projects) and [.NET WebAssembly build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows#net-webassembly-build-tools) to knw more.